# Anyway to specify what should appear in <title> in .php file?

Tags: title

Is there anyway I can set what text should appear in the  tags before get_header() is called in my .php files that are inside my theme's directory?

Comment: get_header() calss header.php which holds the <title> tag in most theme's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your theme how exactly `<title>` is generated. At least some of it should be generated by [`wp_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) function, output of which you can filter at `wp_title` hook.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter for the [get_header hook](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/get_header) and then you can return custom code for the header.